# Skip a row when condition is not met using pandas apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some data which looks like this:

```
    title   type    news_url
0   The U.S. CDC quietly updated their numbers in ...   post    https://www.facebook.com/drelizabethdc/posts/1...
1   Social media posts shared thousands of times a...   post    https://twitter.com/littllemel/status/12997914...
2   Either masks work or they don’t; if masks work...   post    https://www.facebook.com/120381895036072/posts...
3   The RT-PCR test for the virus that causes COVI...   article https://pieceofmindful.com/2020/04/06/bombshel...
4   The Governor of Maine has ordered restaurant s...   article https://summit.news/2020/08/20/governor-of-mai..
```

In the "type" column I have a label which is wither "post" or "article". What I want to do is replace these values with "facebook" if facebook is in the "news_url" column, and "twitter" if twitter is in the "news_url" column.

I have written the following code:

```
def swap_type(x):
    if "facebook" in x:
        return "facebook"
    if "twitter" in x:
        return "twitter"

df_coda_news_fake['type'] = df_coda_news_fake['news_url'].apply(swap_type)
```

What this does is correctly changes the values I want, but if also changes all other values to "None", how can I use the .apply or lambda/apply function to skip all rows where the condition is not met? ie - leave those values unchanged?

I don't want to hardcode an else statement that says `return "article"` for example because this is not always true.

```
title   type    news_url
0   The U.S. CDC quietly updated their numbers in ...   facebook    https://www.facebook.com/drelizabethdc/posts/1...
1   Social media posts shared thousands of times a...   twitter https://twitter.com/littllemel/status/12997914...
2   Either masks work or they don’t; if masks work...   facebook    https://www.facebook.com/120381895036072/posts...
3   The RT-PCR test for the virus that causes COVI...   None    https://pieceofmindful.com/2020/04/06/bombshel...
4   The Governor of Maine has ordered restaurant s...   None    https://summit.news/2020/08/20/governor-of-mai...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` on the whole dataframe instead of just the `news_url` column. Using `axis=1`, your function will be given rows and you can index accordingly:

```py
def swap_type(row):
    if "facebook" in row.news_url:
        row.type = "facebook"
    elif "twitter" in row.news_url:
        row.type = "twitter"
    return row

df_coda_news_fake = df_coda_news_fake.apply(swap_type, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    title                                               type        news_url
0   The U.S. CDC quietly updated their numbers in ...   facebook    https://www.facebook.com/drelizabethdc/posts/1...
1   Social media posts shared thousands of times a...   twitter     https://twitter.com/littllemel/status/12997914...
2   Either masks work or they don’t; if masks work...   facebook    https://www.facebook.com/120381895036072/posts...
3   The RT-PCR test for the virus that causes COVI...   article     https://pieceofmindful.com/2020/04/06/bombshel...
4   The Governor of Maine has ordered restaurant s...   article     https://summit.news/2020/08/20/governor-of-mai..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter those rows:

```
import re
mask = df['news_url'].str.contains(r'(?:facebook)|(?:twitter)', flags=re.I)
df.loc[mask, 'type'] = df[mask]\
                       .apply(lambda x: 'facebook' if 'facebook' in x['news_url'] else 'twitter', axis=1)
```

Comment: Actually I didn't know if my code has any bugs :) Because I couldn't reproduce your data.
Happy to help.

Comment: accepting the answer from @tdy because is most similar to the code I presented. But this works also, cheers.